# Fastest way to change page background color using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, colors, document, styling

What's the smallest and fastest way to modify a document's background color using javascript? it should be cross browser.

I tried the following which didn't work in firebug:

```
   document.body.bgcolor = "#eee";

   document.documentElement.bgcolor = "#eee";
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `backgroundColor` CSS property:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#eeeeee";
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/h4H4n/) is a live demo.